# What comic has sold for the highest price?

Tags: marvel, dc, comics

Which superhero comic (title, issue, year) has sold for the most money. I know Superman No. 1 has sold for incredible amounts of money, but are there others who have sold for more?

Comment: Is this necessarily a science fiction and fantasy question? It *is* possible that the comic that sold for the highest price was not speculative fiction. Perhaps editing it to make it specific to SF comics would clarify things.

Comment: http://www.cbr.com/the-10-most-expensive-comic-books-ever-sold/

Comment: Isn't this question going to need a new answer every time a new record is set? Do you want to compare prices in "constant dollars" (i.e. adjusted for inflation) or "current dollars"?

Comment: This would fall under fandom information, and be on topic, but is way too localized as-written (unfortunately, no longer a close reason).

Comment: Looks like a good question for the _Area51_ proposal _[Comics, Cartoons & Animation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94426/comics-cartoons-animation?referrer=WpIP95MxAOelvQRFh5DO2w2)_ if we ever get that show on the road.

Comment: You seem to be asking about superhero comics, so I edited that in. If you want to include “The Adventures of Tin-Tin,” say, that would probably be off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Mint-quality editions of [Action Comics #1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Comics_1) (featuring the first appearance of Superman) hold all three of the top spots for 'most expensive comic', selling for $1.3m in 2010, $2.16m in 2011 (Nicholas Cage's copy) and most recently for **£3.2m in 2014**.

> *An original copy of the Action Comics #1 that initially cost 10 cents
> and introduced Earth to Superman became the world’s most expensive
> comic book Sunday when it raked in $3.2 million on eBay.*
>
> *When Darren Adams decided to put his incredibly rare, nearly pristine
> copy of the debut issue of the Man of Steel up for auction on eBay, he
> generously started the bid at 99 cents.*
>
> *Less than two hours later, the price had risen faster than a speeding
> bullet, past $1.5 million.*
>
> *When the auction ended Sunday night, the owner of Pristine Comics in
> Federal Way, Wash., discovered that his holy grail of comics had
> scored him $3,207,852.*
>
> <sub><sup>[**World’s most expensive comic book sells for $3.2M**](http://nypost.com/2014/08/25/worlds-most-expensive-comic-book-sells-for-3-2m/)</sup></sub>

[image]

Interestingly, this represents a markup of over nine million percent on its cost of production, just slightly less than printer ink.

---

Excluding Action Comics only a couple of comics have ever broken the $1m barrier.

- A copy of [Amazing Fantasy #15](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/16926/amazing_fantasy_1962_15) (the introduction of Spider Man) sold for $1.1m in 2011.
- A copy of [Detective Comics #27](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_27) (the introduction of Batman) sold for $1.07m in 2010. It has been argued that since a "*Gem Mint*" copy of this edition is still in existence, it could, at least *theoretically*, be the most expensive comic ever sold if it goes to auction.